# How to feed an infinite stream using a queue?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'd like to have several `threads` that read files. The files are `ZIP` files containing several text files itself. Each file thus must be read line by line.

Any content of the files should be send to some kind of `queue`. The queue itself should be processed infinitely from a worker thread.

How could such a scenario be implemented, if possible at all?
Some pseudo-code I came up with, but I really don't know how this could be implemented:

```
Queue<String> queue;

//multiple threads:
BufferedReader br;
queue.add(br.readLine());

//processing thread for the queue:
queue.stream().parallel().forEach(line -> convertAndWrite(line));

//worker function:
private void convertAndWrite(String line) {
    //convert the line to an output format,
    //and write each line eg to an output file or perist in DB, whatever
}
```

Comment: Instead of having threads read files, it'd almost certainly be simpler to do the entire thing as one big parallel stream -- `Stream.of(files).parallel().flatMap(Files::lines).forEach(line -> line.convertAndWrite(line))`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman unfortunately you can't really do it that way since `Files.lines()` throws `IOException`; also, I'm not sure whether its `.close()` method is called in this scenario

Comment: I have to read the files line by line as I directly read from a zip file.

Comment: What do you gain by separating the reading and writing into separate threads? Why not have several worker threads each reading and a writing a single ZIP file.

Comment: @fge: Yes, closing will work properly, but you probably will have to deal with the IOException.  Nevertheless, I'd expect something based around that approach to be easier than trying to streamify a queue like that.

Comment: @djna because I have large zip files containing themselves many files. The processing of the lines + subsequent writing takes the most time, thus I want to parallelize the process. Therefore, ideally I'd feed a queue with read lines from even a single thread (which is fast enough), but process the lines infinite from the queue, async.

Comment: This seems a lot like an xy problem... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: But when you write lines in parallel then you might not get them in a sequence which you received. I hope it will not corrupt the .zip file.

Comment: @membersound You have some finite amount of files with finite amount of strings in them. Why do you say the stream is infinite? Do you actually need to monitor some folder for new files appearance or smth?

Comment: @AndriyKryvtsun exactly: monitor a folder with often new files.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the answer for [How to interconect non-paralel stream with parallel stream(one producer multiple consumers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36791761/how-to-interconect-non-paralel-stream-with-parallel-streamone-producer-multiple). For this problem, a blocking queue was filled using a stream that could not be parallelized.  A parallelizable spliterator was implemented that drained this queue. If you want the files to be contiguous, then you probably have a single reader that's filling the queue.

You then create a stream from the spliterator using StreamSupport. The blocking queue supports concurrent modification, so the spliterator implementation can be parallelized and thus your stream can be parallelized.  If your downstream writer is parallelizable, then your whole consumer side can be parallelized.

If your reader encounters an exception, then you push an End-of-Stream marker (perhaps as part of a final clause) into the BlockingQueue and re-throw. There is only a single tryAdvance caller (see AbstractSpliterator), so a single End-of-Stream marker is sufficient to terminate all parallel streams.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some pseudocode for ya, if you're okay with using a <strike>LinkedList</strike> LinkedBlockingQueue instead of a Queue (although technically a <strike>LinkedList</strike> LinkedBlockingQueue  implements Queue):

```
while (true) {
    if (!(queue.isEmpty())) {
        try {
            TheTypeOfElementsInQueue element = queue.removeFirst();
            // do something with element
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            // just in case!
        }
    }
}
```

I put that into a `run()` of a class implementing runnable, and made a thread out of it. The way I did it was with a LinkedList, but as LinkedLists are not thread safe, perhaps a LinkedBlockingQueue would be better.

Comment: `LinkedList`s are not thread safe. A `LinkedBlockingQueue` would work.

Comment: @brettOkken thanks! I've edited the answer to include your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

To implement the task with monitoring a folder for new files appearance I would use Java [WatchService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html) with streams as showed in [this article](http://howtodoinjava.com/java-8/java-8-watchservice-api-tutorial)

Register for the folder updates via `WatchService`:

```
Path path = Paths.get(".");
WatchService watchService =  path.getFileSystem().newWatchService();
path.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);
```

Get the folder updates and process them via stream:

```
WatchKey watchKey = null;
while (true) {
    watchKey = watchService.poll(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    if(watchKey != null) {
        watchKey.pollEvents().stream().forEach(event -> System.out.println(event.context()));
    }
    watchKey.reset();
}
```

In the line

```
watchKey.pollEvents().stream().forEach(event -> System.out.println(event.context()));
```

I suppose you can use parallel stream and `event.context()` here is a `Path` instance for a new created file. So you can continue processing its content via other stream operations (like `map` etc.)