# How to interconnect non-parallel stream with parallel stream(one producer multiple consumers)

Tags: java, multithreading, java-stream

I am trying to create one producer multiple consumers model with streams in Java8. I am reading and processing data from DB resource and
 I want to process them in streaming fashion way(can not read the whole resource into memory).

The reading of the source has to be single threaded (the cursors is not thread safe) and  reading is fast, than the processing of each data chunks which is heavy operation can run in parallel.

I haven't found out how can I join (interconnect) non-parallel stream with parallel stream processing. Is there any way how to do it with Java8 stream API ?

Example of code:

This iterator has to run in single thread because cursor is not thread safe.

```
class SimpleIterator<Data> implements Iterator<Data>{

    private volatile Cursor cursor;

    public SimpleIterator(Cursor cursor){
        this.cursor = cursor;
    }

   @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return cursor.hasNext();
    }    

    @Override
    public Data next() {
     return cursor.next();

    }
}
```

//create the non-paralel stream

```
SimpleIterator<Data> iterator = new SimpleIterator<>(queryCursor);
Iterable<Data> iterable = () -> iterator;
Stream<Data> resultStream = StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false); // prallel set as false
```

//process data for each data should run in parallel

```
resultStream.parallel().forEach(data->processData(data)); 
public processData(Data data){
//heavy operation
}
```

But if I set stream as parallel before calling forEach than the whole stream is  parallel and also the iterator is calling in multiple threads.
Is there any way how to interconnect this two streams in Java8 or I have to create some queue that will provide data from single threaded producer stream to parallel stream.

Comment: I believe your assumption here is that the Iterator will be called in parallel by multiple threads. That's not entirely correct. It will be called by multiple threads, yes - but not in parallel. What your code does, is creating an IteratorSpliterator of unknown size which wraps your Iterator. Neither the Spliterator nor the Iterator needs to be thread-safe (Fork/Join takes care of this). Think of it like this: is an ArrayList thread-safe? Nope. Can you do parallel stream processing on it? Yes, you can.

Comment: You are right my assumption was exactly like you describe. Thank you for clarifying me this. I still think that there can be some threading problem if multiple threads call my iterator even though they are not running in parallel. For example if cursor wouldn't be  set as volatile than the others thread can see some cache object not the original one(for example).

Comment: Then ensure your cursor is published safely.

The IteratorSpliterator will run over the Iterator in growing batches (each a multiple of 1024, example: 3072, 7168, 11264, ...) and copy the elements from the Iterator into an array that has the current batch size as length. From that array an ArraySpliterator gets created (that could be split further). You'll only see thread switches in the Iterator when one batch has been copied.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. You help me alot.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a problem where I need to do a full outer join on two streams.  The problems appear to be similar. What I do is insert two blocking queues to buffer my input.  I think you can do something similar with one blocking queue to split a single stream into multiple streams without parallelizing the source stream.

The solution I propose can be found below.  I have not tested my solution for joining two streams yet, so I am not certain this works. The AbstractSpliterator class has an implementation of trySplit; the comments on trySplit are informative. The final method of the class constructs a parallelizable stream from the spliterator implementation.

```
import java.util.Spliterators;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class StreamSplitter<T> extends Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator<T> {
    final T EOS = null; // Just a stub -- can't put a null in BlockingQueue

    private final BlockingQueue<T> queue;
    private final Thread thread;

    // An implementation of Runnable that fills a queue from a stream
    private class Filler implements Runnable {
        private final Stream<T> stream;
        private final BlockingQueue<T> queue;

        private Filler(Stream<T> stream, BlockingQueue<T> queue) {
            this.stream = stream;
            this.queue = queue;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            stream.forEach(x -> {
                try {
                    // Blocks if the queue is full
                    queue.put(x);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
            // Stream is drained put end of stream marker.
            try {
                queue.put(EOS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private StreamSplitter(long estSize, int characteristics, Stream<T> srcStream) {
        super(estSize, characteristics);
        queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<T>(1024);
        // Fill the queue from a separate thread (may want to externalize this).
        thread = new Thread(new Filler(srcStream, queue));
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super T> action) {
        try {
            T value = queue.take(); // waits (blocks) for entries in queue

            // If end of stream marker is found, return false signifying
            // that the stream is finished.
            if (value == EOS) {
                return false;
            }
            // Accept the next value.
            action.accept(value);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static <T> Stream<T> splitStream(long estSize, int characteristics, Stream<T> srcStream) {
        Spliterator<T> spliterator = new StreamSplitter<T>(estSize, characteristics, srcStream);
        return StreamSupport.stream(spliterator, true);
    }
}
```